# How can I fix a click incorrectly invoking a Select interaction when autopan'ing an Overlay?

Tags: openlayers

If I set `autopan` to true for the overlay, when I click in the red circle:

1. the overlay appears
2. autopan scrolls the map so the whole overlay is visible
3. The `Select` interaction obtains the click event and causes the rectangle to turn red

If `autopan` is false, when I click in the red circle, the overlay appears, but the `Select` interaction is not invoked.

What I think is happening is after I click, the autopan moves things and when the `Select` interaction checks to see if it needs to handle the click, the code that would prevent it due to the red circle cannot prevent it because the red circle has moved.

It may be necessary to view the code snippet in the full page view so the red circle can be placed near the bottom of the map view and autopan'ing can cause the entire overlay to appear.
How can I resolve this problem?

```js
//
// Create the Rectangle
//
function createRectangle(layerName) {
  const features = [];

  const feature = {
    type: "Feature",
    geometry: {
      type: "Polygon",
      coordinates: [
        [
          [30, 5],
          [30, 30],
          [85, 30],
          [85, 5]
        ]
      ]
    },
    properties: {
      id: `${layerName}`,
      layerName
    }
  };

  features.push(feature);

  const json = {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features
  };

  return json;
}

const rectangle = createRectangle("small");
const rectangleStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: "hsla(120, 50%, 100%, 1.0)",
    width: 5
  }),
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: "hsla(120, 50%, 50%, 0.50)"
  })
});

const rectangleVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
      featureProjection: "EPSG:4326" // 4326 3857
    }).readFeatures(rectangle)
  }),
  style: (feature) => rectangleStyle,
  zIndex: 4,
  properties: {
    name: "small"
  }
});

//
// Create the marker which will have the overlay attached
//

const markerStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Circle({
    radius: 12,
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: "#e00" }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: "black",
      width: 2
    })
  })
});

const markerLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [
      new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point([55, 25])
      })
    ]
  }),
  style: (feature) => markerStyle,
  zIndex: 10
});

//
// Create OSM Layer
//

const osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

//
// Create the Map
//

const map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [osmLayer, rectangleVectorLayer, markerLayer],
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: "EPSG:4326",
    center: [55, 30],
    zoom: 5
  })
});

//
//
//

const selectedStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: "hsla(0, 50%, 50%, 0.5)"
  }),
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: "hsla(0, 50%, 100%, 1)",
    width: 3
  }),
  zIndex: 1
});

const rectangleLayerInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
  style: (feature) => {
    return selectedStyle;
  },
  layers: [rectangleVectorLayer],
  condition: function (e) {
    const isSingleClick = ol.events.condition.singleClick(e);
    let passed = false;

    if (isSingleClick) {
      console.group();
      const features = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(e.pixel, {
        layerFilter: function (l) {
          //console.log(
          //  "rectangle layerFilter",
          //  l.getZIndex(),
          //  rectangleVectorLayer.getZIndex(),
          //  l.getZIndex() > rectangleVectorLayer.getZIndex()
          //);
          return l.getZIndex() > rectangleVectorLayer.getZIndex();
        }
      });
      const noFeatures = features.length === 0;

      passed = isSingleClick && noFeatures;

      //console.log("condition features", features);
      //console.log("condition noFeatures", noFeatures);
      //console.log("condition isSingleClick", isSingleClick);
      //console.log("condition passed", passed);

      console.groupEnd();
    }

    return passed;
  }
});

map.addInteraction(rectangleLayerInteraction);

//
// Add overlay and handler
//

const popup = new ol.Overlay({
  element: document.getElementById("popup"),
  autoPan: true
});

map.addOverlay(popup);

const markerLayerUID = ol.util.getUid(markerLayer);

map.on("click", (e) => {
  const hitFeatures = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(e.pixel, {
    layerFilter: (layer) => {
      return ol.util.getUid(layer) === markerLayerUID;
    }
  });

  //console.log("hitFeatures", hitFeatures);

  if (hitFeatures.length === 1) {
    const position = ol.extent.getBottomLeft(
      hitFeatures[0].getGeometry().getExtent()
    );
    popup.setPosition(position);
  } else {
    popup.setPosition(undefined);
  }
});
```

```css
#map {
  height: 512px;
  width: 1024px;
}

.popup {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.3.0/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.3.0/dist/ol.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>

<div id="popup" class="popup"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the map is animating in your select condition

```
if (isSingleClick && !map.getView().getAnimating()) {
```

Comment: That does work, but feels like a race-condition bug waiting to happen. I am hoping that another pass over the event system within OpenLayers can happen. It would be nice if it was cleaner and clearer. I will add this question to https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/14645